# How do I make NodeJS server understand es6 import and export?

Tags: node.js, gulp

For frontend i'm using gulp [babelify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babelify) 
and browserify
to transpile es6:

```
gulp.task('buildApp', function() {
  return browserify('src/js/main.js')
    .transform(babelify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js')) // gives streaming vinyl file object
    .pipe(buffer()) // <----- convert from streaming to buffered vinyl file object
    .pipe(uglify()) // now gulp-uglify works 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

How do i do the same thing for server? As far as i know, browserify does not work for server code

Comment: You could use webpack

Comment: is it possible to solve this without webpack?

Comment: You could probably just use babel to transpile and remove the dependency of browserify on the server app.

Comment: in this case 'require' and 'import' statements just being ignored

Answer (score 0):

Put your ES6 code into a `/src` directory then simply transpile it with babel into a `/lib` directory and execute the transpiled code. Also babel has a `watch` option for development. You could use `nodemon` to automatically restart the server on a filechange.

`$ babel src --out-dir lib --watch`

Remember to configure babel with the `.babelrc` file.

Check out the babel website for the docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: this looks like workaround. Thank you for answer, anyway

Comment: I don´t really see this as a "workaround". I think there is no easier solution.